# How to determine shape of level curves of $V(y,z)= \ln{ \left( \frac{y^2 + (z+z_o)^2}{y^2 + (z-z_o)^2}\right)} $?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, visualization

Context:

I expect that a circle will be written as
$$R^2 = (x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2,$$
where $R$ is the radius, and $(a,b)$ is the center of the circle.

Question:

How to determine analytically that the level lines of
$$V(y,z)=  \ln{ \left(  \frac{y^2 + (z+z_o)^2}{y^2 + (z-z_o)^2}\right)}$$
are circles?

[image]

Comment: Take exponentials on both sides for constant values of $V$ and you will end up with the equation of a circle.

Comment: Please see my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isocontours of $V$ are represented by constant values of the function, i.e., $V=C$, which yields

$$C = \ln{ \left(  \frac{y^2 + (z+z_o)^2}{y^2 + (z-z_o)^2}\right)} \implies 
\mathrm{e}^C = \left(  \frac{y^2 + (z+z_o)^2}{y^2 + (z-z_o)^2}\right)$$

Now rearrange to have

$$A \left[y^2 + (z-z_o)^2\right] = y^2 + (z+z_o)^2 $$

or, equivalently

$$ (A-1) y^2 + A(z-z_o)^2 - (z+z_o)^2 = 0,$$

with $A = \mathrm{e}^C $. Upon completing the square*, one has (if I didn't mess up)

$$ y^2 + (z-B)^2 = \frac{D}{A-1}, $$

where $B = z_o(A+1)/(A-1)$, and $D = 4Az_o^2/(A-1)$.

---

*Credit to this step goes to [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/23014/defining-a-function-that-completes-the-square-given-a-quadratic-polynomial-expre/23059#23059) answer.